# Find file , extract from other file and post

Tags: bash, shell, find, jq

i have multiple files  and need to do  whit all
So  i  use find .
i need to extract from  .json line 12   and  extract the id from .json.ml
and merge in a CURL PUT

Json file  is:

```
 "title":"Hamaca",
    "price":"620",
    "currency_id":"ARS",
    "available_quantity":"110",
    "buying_mode":"buy_it_now",
    "listing_type_id":"bronze",
    "condition":"new",
    "description":{
  "plain_text": " Text Update"
},
"pictures":[
    {"source":"https://web/img/p/2/9/29.jpg"},
    {"source":"https://web/img/p/3/0/30.jpg"},
    {"source":"https:/qweb/img/p/9/2/3/923.jpg"},
],
    "attributes":[
    {"id":"BRAND",
    "value_name":" TIENDA"  },
    {"id":"MODEL",
    "value_name":"Q" }]
```

Json.ml file:

```
{"id":"MLA745474956","site_id":"MLA","title":"Hamaca","subtitle":null,"seller_id":335445253,"category_id":"MLA94987","official_store_id":null,"price":550,"base_price":550,"original_price":null,"currency_id":"ARS","initial_quantity":110,"available_quantity":110,"sold_quantity":0,"sale_terms":[],"buying_mode":"buy_it_now","listing_type_id":"gold_special","start_time":"2018-08-29T15:00:37.897Z","stop_time":"2038-08-24T04:00:00.000Z","end_time":"2038-08-24T04:00:00.000Z","expiration_time":"2018-11-17T15:00:38.018Z","condition":"new","permalink":"http://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-745474956-hamaca-_JM","pictures":[{"id":"706112-MLA28051912310_082018","url":"http://www.mercadolibre.com/jm/img?s=STC&v=O&f=proccesing_image_es.jpg","secure_url":"https://www.mercadolibre.com/jm/img?s=STC&v=O&f=proccesing_image_es.jpg","size":"500x500","max_size":"500x500","quality":""},{"id":"949384-MLA28051912309_082018","url":"http://www.mercadolibre.com/jm/img?s=STC&v=O&f=proccesing_image_es.jpg","secure_url":"https://www.mercadolibre.com/jm/img?s=STC&v=O&f=proccesing_image_es.jpg","size":"500x500","max_size":"500x500","quality":""},{"id":"803007-MLA28051912308_082018","url":"http://www.mercadolibre.com/jm/img?s=STC&v=O&f=proccesing_image_es.jpg","secure_url":"https://www.mercadolibre.com/jm/img?s=STC&v=O&f=proccesing_image_es.jpg","size":"500x500","max_size":"500x500","quality":""}],"video_id":null,"descriptions":[{"id":"MLA745474956-1797576680"}],"accepts_mercadopago":true,"non_mercado_pago_payment_methods":[],"shipping":{"mode":"me2","local_pick_up":false,"free_shipping":false,"methods":[],"dimensions":null,"tags":[],"logistic_type":"drop_off","store_pick_up":false},"international_delivery_mode":"none","seller_address":{"id":978130375,"comment":"","address_line":"Pastor Luna 6250","zip_code":"1682","city":{"id":"","name":"Tres de febrero"},"state":{"id":"AR-B","name":"Buenos Aires"},"country":{"id":"AR","name":"Argentina"},"latitude":-34.5861404,"longitude":-58.58094730000001,"search_location":{"neighborhood":{"id":"TUxBQlZJTDI2MTc2Mw","name":"Villa Bosch"},"city":{"id":"TUxBQ1RSRTMxODE5NA","name":"Tres de febrero"},"state":{"id":"TUxBUEdSQWVmNTVm","name":"Bs.As. G.B.A. Oeste"}}},"seller_contact":null,"location":{},"geolocation":{"latitude":-34.5861404,"longitude":-58.58094730000001},"coverage_areas":[],"attributes":[{"id":"ITEM_CONDITION","name":"Condición del ítem","value_id":"2230284","value_name":"Nuevo","value_struct":null,"attribute_group_id":"","attribute_group_name":""},{"id":"BRAND","name":"Marca","value_id":null,"value_name":"QUIEROTODO TIENDA","value_struct":null,"attribute_group_id":"OTHERS","attribute_group_name":"Otros"},{"id":"MODEL","name":"Modelo","value_id":null,"value_name":"QPM02","value_struct":null,"attribute_group_id":"OTHERS","attribute_group_name":"Otros"}],"warnings":[],"listing_source":"","variations":[],"thumbnail":"http://www.mercadolibre.com/jm/img?s=STC&v=I&f=proccesing_image_es.jpg","secure_thumbnail":"https://www.mercadolibre.com/jm/img?s=STC&v=I&f=proccesing_image_es.jpg","status":"active","sub_status":[],"tags":["immediate_payment","cart_eligible"],"warranty":"Cambios por falla de fabrica dentro de 72 hs de haber recibido el producto sin indicios de uso en su caja original! Los cambios de talle corren por cuenta del comprador de ida y vuelta sin exepcion. No hacemos reintegro de dinero ni devolcuion de art","catalog_product_id":null,"domain_id":"MLA-PLAYGROUND_SWING_SETS","seller_custom_field":null,"parent_item_id":null,"differential_pricing":null,"deal_ids":[],"automatic_relist":false,"date_created":"2018-08-29T15:00:38.208Z","last_updated":"2018-08-29T15:00:38.208Z","health":null}
```

I need to extract  line 9 from json   and   id from json.ml 
Merge in a Curl

Thx

Here is my code`

```
find . -type f -name '*.json' | xargs bash -c 'for fname

# Check if exist
do if [ ! -e ${fname}.ml ]
then 
desc=$(sed -n "12p"  ${fname})
id=$(cat ${fname}.ml | jq -r ".| .id " )
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  "$desc" https://api.web.com/id/$id/

else
(( acounte++ ))
fi

done

' bash
```

When i run my script  nothing work  but i dont see any error.
Thx

Comment: Please provide a sample JSON file so we can try your code and see how we can help.  You have nothing at all for errors?  Have you tried running it with `#!/bin/bash -x`?  You will see everything it is doing.

Comment: In addition to @Nic3500 comment: In this case also use `... | xargs bash -x -c ...`. btw: `! -e ${fname}.ml` means: If the file does NOT exist.

Comment: Samuel  you r great  i  forget to  delete `!`  =0
But  i can merge the variable in the  CURL  example 
`curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  "$desc" https://api.web.com/id/$id/`
What is wrong ?

Comment: @jess - Please fix your "Json file" so that it is valid JSON. (Quick check: `jq empty input.json`) Also, `.|.id` can be simplified to `.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me how `desc` is supposed to be set, but the following should get you on your way once you've fixed the JSON in the .json file:

```
acounte=0
while read fname
do                    
  # Check if exists and non-empty
  fname=${fname/.json/.ml}
  if [ -s "${fname}" ] ; then 
    # SET desc here
    id=$(jq -r .id "${fname}" )
    echo id="$id" >&2
    curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d  "$desc" "https://api.web.com/id/$id/"
  else
    (( acounte++ ))
  fi
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.json')

echo acounte=$acounte >&2
```